# Cygwin Download Problems

Tags: cygwin

I have a project where I need to compile software for a client. My machine doesn't currently have a compilier, so I'm trying to download Cygwin. I've tried 3 times now, and each time the download froze. Once when it got to 28% and the second two times when it got to 6%.

I'm just running the Setup.exe they give you, adding the Devel packages, and choosing the mirror closest to me.

Any idea how I can get this installed? Or have any suggestions for other tools I can use?

This is the first time I'm actually compiling software, so this all might be a really dumb question, but I'm not sure where else to ask, and the client is in a little bit of a hurry.

Comment: Is the customer going to run the apps on Cygwin as well?  If not, then don't use it.  You may want to look at [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) which will allow you to compile source to native Windows apps with no external libraries required (unlike Cygwin).  See [How To Install MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW) for a getting started guide.

Comment: I've tried 2, but I'll try another. Thanks. It's a pretty long install I assume, right?

Comment: Thanks drew, I'll check it out now

Answer (score 0):

As far as your download problems, I would start by just downloading `setup.exe` and do a stock installation. This will give you the bash environment. After that you can check mirrors if you are having problems

[**sources.redhat.com/cygwin/mirrors.lst**](http://sources.redhat.com/cygwin/mirrors.lst)

As to [drew010’s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9828337/cygwin-download-problems#comment12522267_9828337) comment about portability, this is a common myth about Cygwin. For some time now Cygwin has offered both **MinGW** and **MinGW-w64** compilers, allowing compilation of **Windows native** 32 and 64 bit binaries.

It is only if you choose the Cygwin native `gcc4` package or the like where you will be generating Cygwin dependant binaries. I would avoid using MinGW unless strictly for compiling. MinGW is still using Bash 3 when Bash 4 has been out **since 2009**.

#### Refs

- [ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash)
- [sf.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/bash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/bash)